# How do I detect if the mouse has moved over certain co-ordinate of the window, JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I detect if the mouse has moved over certain co-ordinates of the window, irrespective of scrolling?

It's for a menu I'm working on. Trying to become better at JavaScript/JQuery...Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you care about actual coordinates, or whether you're over a certain element?

Comment: @Diodeus It doesnt matter if it's over a element. I just want the hit area to be 0-100px from the top of the window irrespective of scrolling, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle document.mousemove

```
<script>
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    //$('#msg').html('pageX=' + e.pageX + ' pageY = ' + e.pageY);
    if (e.pageX === 100 && e.pageY === 100) {
        alert('Got there');
    }
});
</script>
```

I believe that [e.pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX) and [e.pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageY) are what you're looking for in terms of the whole document.

If those don't work, try [e.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX) and [e.clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY), which will tell you where the mouse is in the window, and not the document.

Comment: sorry that didnt work. Is there no way of defining a fixed area of the window irrespective of scrolling?